# GeoPandas Intersection cause duplicate columns

Tags: python, geopandas, intersection

I have two dataframes - large and small polygons, and a loop.
What I try to do is loop through large polygons and find corresponding small polygons. The tool to be used is `GeoPandas Overlay`, however, I am experiencing some trouble with the function. What I get is the FutureWarning as the `df_result = gpd.overlay(Polygons, df_i, how='intersection')` creates two `FID_1` columns which in fact are not similar.

> FutureWarning: Passing 'suffixes' which cause duplicate columns
> {'FID_1'} in the result is deprecated and will raise a MergeError in a
> future version. return merge(

And as there are two FID_1 columns, the next line of `df_ii = df_i_result[df_i_result['FID_1'] == i]` gives me an error of: (below).

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Interesting that previously this worked, but then I started to receive the error. I assume that something is wrong with the IDs and FIDs, however it seems that all joins are performed correctly.

```
import geopandas as gpd

Polygons = gpd.read_file(r'E:\...\Polygons.shp')
Small_polygon = gpd.read_file(r'E:\...\Small_polygon.shp')
some_points = gpd.read_file(r'E:\...\points.shp')

print(Polygons.crs == Small_polygon.crs == some_points.crs)
True

# define the ID for each polygon
def ID(file, name):
    file[name]= file.index
    fid = file[name]
    file.drop(labels=[name], axis=1,inplace = True)
    file.insert(0, name, fid)
ID(Polygons, 'FID')
ID(Small_polygon, 'ID')

small_poly_join = gpd.sjoin(Small_polygon, Polygons)[['ID', 'FID', 'geometry']]

for i in Polygons.index:
    df_i = small_poly_join[small_poly_join['FID'] == i]

    df_result = gpd.overlay(Polygons, df_i, how='intersection')
    df_result['area'] = round((df_result.apply(lambda row: row.geometry.area, axis=1)) / 10000, 4)
    print(df_result)
    # df_i_result= df_i_result.loc[:, ~df_i_result.columns.duplicated()]

    df_ii = df_result[df_result['FID_1'] == i]
    df_ii['area'] = round(df_ii['area'], 4)
    print(df_ii)
```

The example of `print(df_result):`

```
    FID_1  FID_1  ...                                           geometry    area
0       0      0  ...  POLYGON ((562292.000 263440.328, 562294.921 26...  0.0043
1       0      0  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((562252.981 263422.189, 562254....  0.0062
2     134    208  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((562071.647 263484.130, 562073....  0.1006
3       0      0  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((562272.212 263310.157, 562271....  0.4808
4       0      0  ...  POLYGON ((562327.756 263289.950, 562328.000 26...  0.0722
5       0      0  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((562326.421 263296.000, 562322....  0.2374
6       7     10  ...  POLYGON ((562380.694 263276.000, 562357.181 26...  0.5981
```

If I run the code adding the following line to remove the duplicated line, I got error:

```
   df_i_result= df_i_result.loc[:, ~df_i_result.columns.duplicated()]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'GeometryArray' and 'int'
```

So the question would be, how to avoid two FID_1 columns creation using `df_result = gpd.overlay(Polygons, df_i, how='intersection')`. Am I missing something, perhaps some small detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this by adding the rename column line after small and large polygon spatial join. As the FID is large polygon index and the one that duplicates later on in the loop, I change the name to FIDi and this did the trick:

```
small_poly_join = gpd.sjoin(Small_polygon, Polygons)[['ID', 'FID', 'geometry']]
small_poly_join = small_poly_join.rename(columns={'FID':'FIDi'})
```

After this I changed the FID_1 name to FID in the loop, as there are no FID_1 and FID_1 duplicate columns created while intersecting. This is really specific, however maybe someone someday finds it useful:

```
 df_ii = df_result[df_result['FID'] == i]
```